# Unrelated div moves during transform of another element

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, css-transitions

On [this page](http://google.com), when you hover over the red stamp in the upper right corner, css3 transform rotates the image. This works as expected but div.last.half briefly clicks to the right and back to it's original position.

This only appears in Chrome 24.0.1312.35 beta-m.

I am unable to figure out what is causing this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is?  I tried clicking all around the stamp and couldn't get it to do anything weird.  (I am using Chrome Beta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Chrome. It is probably related to GPU compositing. The problem does reproduce for me in Chrome 23.0.1271.95 (Official Build 169798) on Mac, but does not reproduce for me in Chrome 25.0.1358.0 (Official Build 172524) canary on Mac. If this is a bug in Chrome, it is possible that the bug has been fixed.

If you need a workaround immediately you could try forcing the area that shimmers to be composited. For example, by changing `<div id="main" …>` to have this inline style `style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);"` this shimmering no longer occurs for me.